# Общее время конвертирования в ffmpeg

Tags: конвертация, ffmpeg, конвертер

Здравствуйте, как можно узнать, сколько было затрачено времени на конвертирование видео файла в ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1):

а что если сделать так:

```
time ffmpeg ....
```